# Unable to install break point in Transactional Spring Service

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring Service which is called from controller. This service uses DAOs to retrieve some data. Until yesterday, code was working correctly and I could put a breakpoint inside a method.

```
class Dao {
   Foo find(string id){
     ... //working breakpoint
   } 
}
```

Yesterday I enabled lazy-loading and added transaction to service:

```
class Dao {
   Foo find(string id){
     ... //working breakpoint
   } 
}

@Service
@Transactional
class MySerivce {
   @Autowired
   Dao dao;

   Foo findById(string id){
     ... //not working breakpoint
   } 
}
```

The code works fine but Eclipse throws "Unable to install breakpoint in ... Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes." when I put a breakpoint anywhere in the service. I checked and the "generate line number attributes" option is enabled.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I guess you tried the usual suspects: Clearing all breakpoints, cleaning and rebuilding the project, -clean start eclipse.... ?

Comment: Yes + reimporting all projects

Comment: and if you remove the transaction annotations and lazy fetching it works again?

Comment: Unfortunately yes ;/

Comment: Two more things to check. 1.) What happens if you only use lazy fetching/ @Transactionsal?  2.) Are you sure the code is acutally reloaded properly (e.g. checking by adding a log statement where you would have put the breakpoint)

Comment: 1) only lazy: "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one ... here"
only @Transactional: "Unable to install breakpoint in ..."

2) Yes, I added System.out.print..." to make sure